# Is there an option to run my code snippet automatically when opening Stack Overflow questions?

Tags: support, stack-snippets

Is it possible to autorun a code snippet?

I would like to run my snippet automatically in the question below:

*[How to add a nice stroke to shining text with given font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67080486/how-to-add-a-nice-stroke-to-shining-text-with-given-font)*

Comment: i mean, there's probably some userscript you can create to do that on your own browser, but having user-submitted code auto-run on other people's machines would not be good.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend you to even make a userscript to do that. What if a snippet contains malware, or code to crash your browser?

Comment: Then it would get flagged and dele... oh, wait

Comment: most of the snippets contain one shot animation so the time you scroll to them, the animation is already done

Comment: It's also worth remembering that any potential answerers *will* run your snippet. It needn't be forced with a site feature; anyone reading a question and wanting to understand it will run an included snippet.

Answer (score 18):

No, there is no such option.

I also think such option would be open to abuse.

Some argue you will miss the juicy animation as it is already done once the snippet scrolls into view.

I prefer to click a button.

If warranted maybe add some explanation in the question why clicking the button to run the snippet is beneficial.